# JavaFX KeyTypedEvent conflit with KeyPressed and KeyReleasedEvent

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent, typed

```
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                System.out.println("space pressed");
            }
        }
    });
    scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
                System.out.println("space released");
            }
        }
    });
    scene.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
            if (ke.getCode() != KeyCode.SPACE) {
                System.out.println("typed");
            }
        }
    });
```

JavaFX KeyTypedEvent conflit with KeyPressed and KeyReleasedEvent.

Why I press SPACE key, also print "Typed", It's strange.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html):

> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the
>   platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode
>   character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about
>   character input. In the simplest case, a key typed event is produced
>   by a single key press (e.g., 'a'). Often, however, characters are
>   produced by series of key presses (e.g., SHIFT + 'a'), and the mapping
>   from key pressed events to key typed events may be many-to-one or
>   many-to-many. Key releases are not usually necessary to generate a key
>   typed event, but there are some cases where the key typed event is not
>   generated until a key is released (e.g., entering ASCII sequences via
>   the Alt-Numpad method in Windows). No key typed events are generated
>   for keys that don't generate Unicode characters (e.g., action keys,
>   modifier keys, etc.).
>
> The char variable always contains a valid Unicode character or
>   CHAR_UNDEFINED. Character input is reported by key typed events; key
>   pressed and key released events are not necessarily associated with
>   character input. Therefore, the char variable is guaranteed to be
>   meaningful only for key typed events.
>
> For key pressed and key released events, the code variable contains
>   the event's key code. For key typed events, the code variable always
>   contains KeyCode.UNDEFINED.
>
> "Key pressed" and "key released" events are lower-level and depend on
>   the platform and keyboard layout. They are generated whenever a key is
>   pressed or released, and are the only way to find out about keys that
>   don't generate character input (e.g., action keys, modifier keys,
>   etc.). The key being pressed or released is indicated by the code
>   variable, which contains a virtual key code.

Basically said, "Key typed" events are *input* events while "Key pressed" and "Key released" events are *keyboard* events.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now use KeyReleased event instead of KeyTyped event, it's OK.